# How do I use if statement or for loop for this project?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, project

I'm making a project that prints out the outcome for this:
Denmark: first 1000 Euro no tax, 10% on the second 1000 (in addition to it), 20% on the
third 1000 (in addition to it), and so on...

If the input is: 6100 then:

Denmark:

```
0.0 * 1000 + 0.1 * 1000 + 0.2 * 1000 + 0.3 * 1000 + 0.4 * 1000 + 0.5 * 1000 + 0.6 * 100 = 1560.0
```

How can I make this happen with a if statement or a for loop?

I tried using this, but I saw that this wouldn't work.

```
income = int(input('Income: '))

percent_counter = 0
income_counter = 0

if income > 1000:
    no_tax = 0.0 * 1000
    percent_counter += 0.1
    income_counter += 1000 
else:
    no_tax = 0.0 * income
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try by doing :

```
income = int(input('Income: '))
tax = 0
percent = 0

for i in range(int(income/1000)):
    tax += percent * 1000
    percent += 0.1
tax += percent * (income%1000)

print("Tax:", tax)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using list comprehension:

```
income = int(input("Income: "))
percents = [i/10 for i in range(income//1000)]
tax = sum(percents)*1000
tax += (percents[-1]+0.1)*(income%1000)
print(tax)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't use lists.